Show two dimensons in a wms layer with leaflet
I have a map and a WMS layer with two dimensions (time and height). I have used leaflet timedimension to show time, but I can not to display the second dimension (height) in the map. Is it possible to do it?
let timeDimension = new L.TimeDimension({
    period: "PT3H",
    timeInterval: "2024-12-22T15:00:00.000Z" + "/PT36H" 
});
    
map.timeDimension = timeDimension; 

let player        = new L.TimeDimension.Player({
    transitionTime: 1500,
}, timeDimension);

let timeDimensionControlOptions = {
    player:        player,
    timeDimension: timeDimension,
    position:      'bottomleft',
    autoPlay: false,
    loopButton: true,
    timeSteps: 1,
    playReverseButton: false,
    limitSliders: true,
};
let timeDimensionControl = new L.Control.TimeDimension(timeDimensionControlOptions);
map.addControl(timeDimensionControl);
let turbTimeLayer = L.timeDimension.layer.wms(turb, {
    updateTimeDimension: true,
});
turbTimeLayer.addTo(map);

I have tried to add a second timeDimensionControl, and I also used the pluging leaflet slidercontrol.
